# What is the mistake in this combinational logic circuit diagram?

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, logic-gates

I am trying to represent the combinational logic circuit to perform 5x3 multiplier operation using 1-bit full adder using CSEDAR Simulator, the label is based on this operations:
[image]

My answer is as below, but the problem is that some operations work correctly like (11101 * 101) while others like (11001 * 111), can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?
[image]

Comment: It seems that one adder (which output T2)has no CI input ?

Comment: Amida, I've already discussed it [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/258106/38098). Did you do any searches on this site? You can also compare a [standard and Wallace design for 4 bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9vV6.png), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row of your multiplier always needs 5 adders and carry signals must never propagate between rows, they may only go from right to left within a row. Carry-in of the adder producing T3 should be connected to ground. Insert another adder in the "N5" trace; connect the carry-out from "M5+N4" to it (instead of to T3).